# Multiple javascript files conflict

Tags: javascript, html, forms, conflict

I'm currently making a form for uploading new members to a web page. I built the form using JotForm which includes js files for controlling the style (hide/show fields, fields that are required turn red, etc.)

The js for this form worked fine on its own, but I also included a picture crop/upload as an extra. This also worked when I was testing it in a separate web page on its own, but now combined with the form, the js conflicts and I don't know how to stop that.
My script head section looks like this:

```
<!-- Jotform js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms/static/prototype.forms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jotfor.ms/static/jotform.forms.js?3.3.10027" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    JotForm.setConditions([{"action":[{"id":"action_0_1448505712729","visibility":"Show","isError":false,"field":"77"}],"id":"1448505521328","index":"0","link":"Any","priority":"0","terms":[{"id":"term_2_1448505712729","field":"68","operator":"equals","value":"Librarian","isError":false},{"id":"term_1448505745204","field":"68","operator":"equals","value":"Social Sec.","isError":false},{"id":"term_1448505752197","field":"68","operator":"equals","value":"Press & Publicity","isError":false},{"id":"term_1448505759596","field":"68","operator":"equals","value":"Webmaster","isError":false},{"id":"term_1448505768860","field":"68","operator":"equals","value":"Tour Manager","isError":false},{"id":"term_1448505778873","field":"68","operator":"equals","value":"Merch Rep.","isError":false},{"id":"term_1448505785856","field":"68","operator":"equals","value":"Ordinary Member","isError":false}],"type":"field"}]);
    JotForm.init(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('input_76').hint('e.g. 1st, 2nd, 3rd');
        }, 20);
        JotForm.clearFieldOnHide="disable";
        JotForm.onSubmissionError="jumpToSubmit";
    });
</script>
<!-- Image cropper js -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cropit.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Because the prototype.forms.js and jotform.forms.js appear first, they seem to work whilst the image cropper does not.
If I put the image cropper files first, the reverse happens and the image cropper works but the other javascript doesn't.

Having read up on this a lot of people talk about this being jQuery conflicts, but I'm not entirely sure what the problem/solution is. All I want is for both features to work simultaneously.

All help appreciated, thanks.

Source (image cropper working only): http://concert-band.co.uk/new/Forms/index2.php

Source (form validation working only): http://concert-band.co.uk/new/Forms/index3.php

Comment: Looks like prototype isn't playing well with jQuery. jQuery has a noconflict option - see the docs https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: try to stick with some prototype extension..

http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/

Comment: I've looked at the docs, and at everyone's suggestions for using `jquery.noConflict()` but none of the suggested solutions worked. I'm not entirely sure my conflict problem is even jQuery related. I was hoping someone could have a look at the sources and provide a more specific answer

Comment: webdeb - I appreciate you finding an alternative but I'm sticking with the crop tool I currently have on the page.

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6272462/1908331 ? I mean I read your comment about `jquery.noConflict()` but have you tried adding the second _which is essential_ also?

Comment: if you mean the `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` bit, there's not 'doc ument ready' line in my js files in the first place if you look. This is why I can't figure out what the conflict is because there appears to be little or no jQuery in the js files to change. If you give me code example of what should be replaced/moved, I'd understand it better

Answer (score 0):

Slightly my fault as I realised that there was no conflict with the `index.js` or `jquery.cropit.js`, it was actually some embedded jquery at the bottom of my `<body>` I had forgotten was there. I've now implemented `jQuery.noConflict()` the normal way and it works fine. Thanks for your help.